# How can I configure sticky scrolling of tree views in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I noticed that in VS Code 1.85, tree views like the Explorer View now support sticky scrolling. How can I enable or disable this feature, and how else can it be configured?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be enabled or disabled using the `workbench.tree.enableStickyScroll` [setting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings). The default value is `true` (enabled).

The other setting that currently exists for it is `workbench.tree.stickyScrollMaxItemCount`:

> Controls the number of sticky elements displayed in the tree when #workbench.tree.enableStickyScroll# is enabled.

You can find the related issue ticket at [Tree: Support sticky scroll
#161207](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/161207). Related release notes are [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_85#_sticky-scroll-in-trees). You should later also be able to use the right click / context menu to toggle it (see [issue #199381](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/199381)).

See also the [Sticky Scroll documentation page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_sticky-scroll).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The sticky scrolling can be enabled or disabled in the settings. Just go settings and type "sticky".

Enable / Disable like in the picture below.